# Shorten/DRY this python if statement?

Tags: python, logic

```
if a == arg:
    if arg not in a_list:
        do_something(arg)
elif b == arg:
    if arg not in b_list:
        do_something(arg)
else:
    do_something_else(arg)
```

Propose an idiomatic way to shorten and specifically DRY above statements - without extracting parts of it to separate functions.

edit: Funny ;-) This not a homework assignment neither is this a request to review my code, perhaps if I reframe above as below my intentions become more clear:

What is a pythonian way to write above if-statements such that it is both DRY and idiomatic to the language? I feel I am missing something, perhaps one can make use of the and/or operators in python? Reason for not extracting any parts of it to separate functions is that then this question is more about refactoring than about idiomatic pythonian if-logic.

Comment: can it be a function where you get "X" and "X_list" ? or do you always have a,b,a_list,b_list ?

what exactly is match doing? what type of object is `a` and `b`?

Comment: *“without extracting parts of it to separate functions”* – why?

Comment: `"extracting parts of it to separate functions" == DRY`

Comment: @InbarRose Thank you for your question, I've edited the text to reflect that the method and type is of no concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple answer:

```
for i, i_list  in [(a, a_list), (b, b_list)]:
    if i == arg:
        if arg not in i_list:
            do_something(arg)
        break
else:
    do_something_else(arg)
```

Combining the `a`, and `a_list` and `b`, and `b_list` into tuples, we can easier iterate them.
Then its a simple matter of the iteration itself, matching the conditions, and running the desired function..

Python supports `for....else` statements.

The else statement will run if there are no returns or breaks in the for loop.

Here, if we get our desired match, the loop will break, and we are done. if we never break, then we get to our else loop. In my opinion this is the most *Pythonic* way to do this.

**Edit**

To make this any better, you should have `a, b, a_list, b_list` inside some kind of dictionary, where `d[a] = a_list`

Then you could just iterate over the dict like this:

```
for k, v  in d.items():
    if k == arg:
        if arg not in v:
            do_something(arg)
        break
else:
    do_something_else(arg)
```

It's almost the same thing, but it looks nicer, and you can have all your `a`'s and `b`'s and lists all sorted out before hand.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the type of answer I was looking for! Appreciate your time InbarRose

Comment: I think there is some difference. If `b == arg` but `b in b_list` then your code will call `do_something_else` but original code will not do anything.

Comment: @Igor you are right. i will fix this in a moment. - it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
def run_for_match(candidate, patterns, search_lists, handlers, default_handler):
    for pattern, search_list, handler in zip(patterns, search_lists, handlers):
        if match(pattern, candidate):
            if candidate not in search_list:
                handler(candidate)
            break
    else:
        default_handler(candidate)

run_for_match(string, [a, b], [a_list, b_list], [do_something, do_something], do_something_else)
```

Though putting this in to an object that encapsulates the `patterns`, `search_lists`, `handlers`, and `default_handler` makes an awful lot of sense.  Something like:

```
class StringHandlerManager(object):

    def __init__(self, default_handler):
        self.handler_registry = []
        self.default_handler = default_handler

    def add_handler(self, pattern, search_list, handler):
        self.handler_registry.append((pattern, search_list, handler))

    def __call__(self, candidate):
        for pattern, search_list, handler in self.handler_registry:
            if match(pattern, candidate):
                if candidate not in search_list:
                    handler(candidate)
                break
        else:
            default_handler(candidate)

handle_string = StringHandlerManager(do_something_else)
handle_string.add_handler(a, a_list, do_something)
handle_string.add_handler(b, b_list, do_something)
handle_string(string)
```